# 'Missing endcsname inserted' error when using \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, errors

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{underscore}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} 

blurb goes here...........


\end{document}
```

This works ok, but when I add the following code for a figure in between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, it blows up:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{flemish_bathy_50m.png}
\end{figure}
```

Giving tons of errors like this:

```
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
unhbox
l.15 ...graphics[scale=0.3]{flemish_bathy_50m.png}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! Undefined control sequence.
GenericError ...
#4 errhelp @err@ ...
l.15 ...graphics[scale=0.3]{flemish_bathy_50m.png}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
GenericError ...
let @err@ ...
l.15 ...graphics[scale=0.3]{flemish_bathy_50m.png}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
GenericError ...
```

The png file is in the same directory as the tex file.

Comment: I have no problems in a current texlive, but try if it works if your remove the underscore package.

Comment: You added `\usepackage{underscore}` to give `_` a non standard meaning, so you get non standard behaviour of `_` in filenames.

Comment: you could use `\string_` or not use the underscore package, or report an issue to the package author

Comment: @DavidCarlisle taking out the underscore package and renaming the image file to not use underscores in the name worked, thanks.

Comment: underscores are not an issue normally, so you only needed to do either one of those things, not both, you could report this to the underscore package author, it is probably easy to fix.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle someone has fixed that. I get an error in texlive 2019, but in texlive 2020 and newer it works fine.